# Lazarus Indy SSL IdHTTP

Tags: linux, ubuntu, openssl, indy, lazarus

I'm trying to get Indy to work with SSL and the IdHTTP component in Lazarus installed on Ubuntu 11. I know my code is right for the http post since if I remove the https and leave it as only http it works. So I figure it's the SSL and indy's components missing Linux libraries. For window's I was use to just including the two DLL's, `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll` and it worked fine.

But in linux it seems to be another story. The only code I have is the post code:

```
IdHttp1.Post('url', StringList, ReturnStreamList);
```

Like I said it works great without the https, but when I try SSL nothing happens at all. No error since I have `try` and `except` to catch but I'm not doing anything with the catching.

I do have OpenSSL installed, I also have the following installed through `apt`:

```
libcrypto++8
libcrypto++-dev
libssl-dev
libssl0.9.8
```

I went to `/usr/lib` and both the files `libcrypto.so` and `libssl.so` are there.

Any ideas what's missing to get SSL to work with Lazarus and Indy for IdHTTP post operations?

EDIT: Ok, after following advice below I have added the exception:

```
on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
       showmessage(htp1.ResponseText);
```

This gives me the error `Error creating SSL context`.

EDIT2: I ran an strace and I have pasted the output areas where it open's the SSL libraries here:
http://pastebin.com/fL6tTSGg

Comment: If you're getting no error because you're throwing away the exception, **stop throwing away the exception** so you know where to find the problem. Seems like a very logical start to solving the problem to me, anyway. :-)

Comment: Yes your right, but i've spent an hour on google and not found the exception to grab in laz for indy. So i can't show it if i don't know what to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was so easy it ticks me off! ha ha

Seems I was using the wrong method for the SSL. I had to set `TidSSLioHandlerSocketOpenSSL.SSLOptions.Method` to `sslvSSLv23`, it was on `sslvSSLv2`.

Now everything works fine :)